# Creating a ResourcePool with units that have different properties

Tags: java, anylogic

I need to create a ResourcePool of workers. However each worker can have different qualifications (properties). For example, ResourcePool named 'Workers' should include different types of workers (e.g. welders, engineers, etc.).
Then, I have a seize block for some production process. I want the seize block to seize workers from the ResourcePool 'Workers', however under the condition that these workers match the requirements for this particular production process.
For example, I have a production process that requires an engineer. I want to seize an engineer from the ResourcePool 'Workers', however the ResourcePool should also include other workers and not only engineers.
The problem is that one worker can be for example an engineer and a welder at the same time. If I create a resource pool for engineers and welders separately, then this one worker, who is both an engineer and a welder will be represented as two separate workers. This is not wanted in my case.
How can this be implemented in AnyLogic?

Comment: Why you think it is a must to all workers to belong to one resource pool? Why not to create different resource pools?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov the problem is that one worker can be for example an engineer and a welder at the same time. If I create a resource pool for engineers and welders separately, then this one worker, who is both an engineer and a welder will be represented as two separate workers. This is not wanted in my case.

Comment: okay, then this is an interesting question! When you ask question on SOF, please include all these details to avoid being downvoted...without this detail, the question seems of too low quality (no research done).

Comment: @sigizmundt2See my udpated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your different resources in different resource pools and then you can seize them using seize blocks. Have different seize blocks for different processes.

And more the seize blocks are very flexible

See the example below - you can seize a different number of resources from different sets or use alternative sets

[image]

Read more here https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/seize.html#seize

[Update after edit]

If you need to select specific resources from within a resource pool you can use the Customize resource choice option to select those resources that have the specific characteristic that you need. See example below and read the help for more

[image]

(engineer is a boolean variable inside my Worker agent, which is of a Resource Type agent, and requiresEngineer is a boolean variable inside the agents that gets created by the source)
In this example, only units that require an engineer will seize an engineer and vice versa. You can customize this as you need.